# Como validar um input à medida que o seu conteúdo muda?

Tags: javascript

Gostava que à medida que preenchesse um dado `input` este fosse sendo validado, ou seja, à medida que fosse preenchendo um campo 'nif' que me fosse alertado uma mensagem de "nif inválido" até este estar correto e que não necessitasse de usar métodos como o `onBlur`.

Alguém conhece alguma maneira de o fazer?

O meu código:

```js
function teste(){
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

  if(input == 5){
     document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = "sucesso";
  }else{
     document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = "insucesso";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onchange='teste()'>
<h2 id="5"> </h2>
```

Comment: Você tem algum código desenvolvido?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: W3Schools é um problema, não usem link deles.
Se você procurar por [keypress na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) vão ver que o evento é descontinuado e o aconselhado é usar o evento [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) ou [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeinput). Sem contar que na MDN ensina a usar `addEventListener` (que é a melhor maneira) ao invés de evento em atributos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Com o evento [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)  você já consegue fazer sua validação. Se você utilizar o [onkeydown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) a validação não ficará correta pois o seu input não terá o valor atual pressionado.

**Veja um exemplo:**

```html
<html>
<body>

<h1>Input validation test</h1>

<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" id='ipt' placeholder='Sucesso'>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById('ipt').value == "Sucesso")
    document.getElementById('ipt').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  else
    document.getElementById('ipt').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 7):

Desnecessário o uso de Javascript (aliás, [você não precisa de JS para muita coisa](http://youmightnotneedjs.com/)), tampouco jQuery. Usar um [modelo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) simples de validação no `<input>` já lhe dá o resultado esperado:

```css
input:invalid ~ [data-input-message]::after{
  content: 'Insira o valor 5';
  color: red
}

input:valid ~ [data-input-message]::after{
  content: 'Obrigado :)';
  color: green
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='Insira o valor 5' pattern='[5]' required>
<span data-input-message></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem outro atributo de evento que chama a função à medida que digita no campo, que é o `oninput`:

```js
function teste(){
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

  if(input == 5){
  document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = "sucesso";

  }else{
    document.getElementById("5").innerHTML = "insucesso";
  }
}
```

```html
Digite 5:
<br>
<input type="text" id="input" oninput='teste()'>
<h2 id="5"> </h2>
```